# Turn text from entry into a string in Python tkinter

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to use the string you type into the `entry_1` Entry but I can't even print it out. So when you type something in and submit it I want to display it in the console with button001.

Here is the code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label_1 = Label(root, text="Username:")
label_2 = Label(root, text="Password:")

info = StringVar()
entry_1 = Entry(root, textvariable="info")

def button001(event):
  print(str(info.get()))

entry_2 = Entry(root)

submitButton = Button(root, text="submit")

submitButton.bind("<Button-1>", button001)
submitButton.grid(row="0", column="2")

label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

c  = Checkbutton(root, text="Keep me logged in.")
c.grid(columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't link the code to Github, edit your question and post your code there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
info = StringVar()
entry_1 = Entry(root, textvariable="info")
```

It needs to be this instead:

```
info = StringVar()
entry_1 = Entry(root, textvariable=info)
```

---

By the way, with such a simple program you don't need `info` at all. You can directly fetch the value from the widget, eliminating one additional object that needs to be managed. Also, there's no need to convert the value to a string because `get` will return a string.

For example:

```
entry_1 = Entry(root)
...
def button001(event):
  print(entry_1.get())
```

Finally, you aren't using the button properly. With the `Button` widget, it's normally best to use the `command` attribute rather than `bind` unless you explicitly need the `event` object:

```
def button001():
    print(entry_1.get())
...
submitButton = Button(root, text="submit", command=button001)
```